# toastr notifcation not appearing mvc 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, toast

Hi I'm new to MVC and I've been trying to build upon a tutorial i've been following by trying to get a toastr message to appear when I successfully edit something in my mvc app. I think I have everything done correctly, but yet the notification isn't popping.

```
    bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include("~/Content/site.css",
            "~/Content/toastr.css"));

    bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js",
        "~/Scripts/toastr.js"));
```

I have toaster added to my scripts and my css, and both bundles are being rendered in the layout view. 
In my edit action, if it is successful I am redirecting to the Index action and adding a message.

```
         [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Edit(Restaurant restaurant)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Entry(restaurant).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index", new { message = "Added" });
        }
        return View(restaurant);
    }


    public ActionResult Index(string message )
    {

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(message))
        {
            ViewBag.message = message;
        }

        return View(db.Restaurants.ToList());
    }
```

Then in the index action I'm checking if it's not empty, if it isn't i'm passing the message into the viewbag. Then in the Index view I am checking if the viewbag is not empty

```
        @model IEnumerable<OdeToFoodNov1.Models.Restaurant>

     @{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
     }

    <h2>Index</h2>

   <p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
   </p>
   <table>
     <tr>
     <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.City)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Country)
    </th>
    <th></th>
</tr>

 @foreach (var item in Model) {
<tr>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.City)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Country)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.Id }) |
        @Html.ActionLink("Reviews", "Index", "Reviews", new { id=item.Id }, null) |
        @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.Id })
    </td>
</tr>
  }

</table>


  @if (ViewBag.message != null)
    {

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        toastr.success('Added')
    })
</script>
   }
```

Yet when I go back to the index view I get no notification appearing? Any help is appreciated, sorry if i'm missing something obvious.

Comment: I would wager the problem is the location of your script... Try checking your browser console and looking for any errors.. I suspect you will find something about $ not defined in there. MVC defaults to putting the scripts at the bottom of an HTML file, and here, I suspect you're trying to call jQuery before it's included on the page

Comment: I think that's it, do you know where I should put that code so that it's loaded after my jquery bundle? Thanks for your help.

Comment: See my answer for a solution :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most MVC layout files include an optional section called scripts (unless the author removed it for some reason).

Look for a line that looks like this in the layout file

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
@RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
```

In this case any Javascript that you want to inject directly into your views would be loaded into the final HTML *after* jQuery is loaded.

Try doing something like this so that you can ensure that your injected JS is loaded into the optional scripts section

```
@section scripts {
    @if (ViewBag.message != null)
    {
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            toastr.success('Added')
        });
    </script>
    }
}
```